# Request to Spring Boot application via Cloudfront fails inexplicably with 403 status

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I navigate to `web.mysite.com`, a static SPA hosted in S3, it has an iframe which has a `src` of `mysite.com/some/path`, which is a Spring Boot MVC application in Elastic Beanstalk. Both are behind Cloudfront distributions for HTTPS. This path is handled in the application with a custom resource resolver. This loads successfully, but inside the iframe content there is a script tag looking for `mysite.com/some/path/thatsdifferent`, handled by the same resolver.

This second request fails with a 403 and I cannot determine why. Navigating to the failing `mysite.com/some/path/thatsdifferent` directly in my browser or using postman succeeds with a 200 status. The server is configured to allow requests from `web.mysite.com` through CORS configuration (and there is no CORS-related error message) and Spring Security is configured to `permitAll` any requests to `/some/**` regardless of authentication. There is no response body or error message beyond the header `x-cache: Error from cloudfront`.

If I navigate to `the-beanstalk-env-url.com/some/path`, it loads the html and then successfully loads the content from `the-beanstalk-env-url.com/some/path/thatsdifferent`.

Requests to a few different but similar paths succeed. Going to a path which definitely 100% does not exists returns a 404.

The server logs show that the request is being successfully handled and Cloudfront is returning reasonable responses to the client. Looking at the Cloudfront logs simply reports a 403, without any additional information.

Almost 100% of Cloudfront 403 error articles and questions involve S3, which is not the part which is failing here.

Changing the Cloudfront distribution Allowed Methods from `GET, HEAD` to `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS` causes the requests directly to `mysite.com/some/path/thatsdifferent` to begin failing with `invalid CORS request`, this was fixed by whitelisting the `Accept, Authorization, Host, Origin` and `Referer` headers. This did not fix the underlying error.

Adjusting the logging for `org.springframework.security` doesn't log any extra information when a failing request occurs, my application security configuration is not what is causing the error.

After replacing Cloudfront with a load balancer on my environment in Route 53, the scenario works as expected, so the problem is definitely in Cloudfront.

Comment: Increase your spring security logging and redeploy/retest.  This will hopefully give you more information on the nature of the failure.

Comment: @AndyN Increasing the level to DEBUG doesn't log anything. Spring is handling the request as it should, meaning it is not being blocked by my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to switch the Cloudfront Origin Protocol policy from `HTTP Only` to `HTTPS Only`.

I don't know why this mattered from the script file and not the html file, but I decided to test it out when I discovered that if I tried to connect to the Beanstalk environment URL via https, Chrome was warning me that the certificate being used was setup for the domain that was served by the Cloudfront distribution that was causing trouble.

Comment: I have done what you suggested. But it works now partly. Some endpoints work with 200 and other endpoints with 502. Have no idea why. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I add a new certificate and made the connection to EBS throw a loadbalancer. I see that all the requests is going throw https. But now I'm getting 403 only on the endpoints that have the spring security in them